# Creating and editing a .fnt file based on a PNG source

Tags: java, libgdx, graphics, fonts, spritefont

I am currently making a game, (obviously), with the LIBGDX Java Library. I have already made a font, (It's a PNG file, not a TTF or RTF), that looks something like this:

(It's a mockup, by the way.)

[image: Hello World!]

I've tried programs like Shoebox to create my font automagically, but it doesn't recognize my font.

Can someone explain how I can just make my own .FNT config file?

Thanks in advance!

Plug  [image: ❤]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably just to redraw it maually, using a simple .fon editor like [Fony](http://hukka.ncn.fi/?fony).

It will probably take less than a hour.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Hiero** for generating the .FNT file using your .ttf font file. Go through the link and download it.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've made it more clear in the post. The font I'm using is a PNG Image, not a TTF or RTF. I've used Heiro before, but, as you said, it only can only convert vector fonts to bitmap fonts. Thanks for trying, though!